# Issue with limiting number of times a value can be inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query below that is inserting correctly the way it is written. However, I am running into issues when trying to modify the query to only insert the value of column 'coord' a maximum of 5 times.

For example if the column 'coord' = 'North'. I need to limit the number of times the 'North' can be inserted. If 10 records with 'coord' = 'North' is already in the database 5 times, then the next value of 'coord' should be selected based on the where clause criteria.

```
SELECT ID, ROUTE into #TEMP_DISTANCE FROM TRAN_TBL
where handle = 21;


SELECT coord, travels into #temp_planned
FROM converse_TBL


WITH TravelPlansInfo AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        Route,
        COUNT(1) AS rowcnt
    FROM  
        #TRAN_TBL
    GROUP BY
        ID, 
        Route
)
, rownum_matches AS (
SELECT 
    t.ID, 
    r.coord,
    t.rowcnt,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY newid()) AS rownum
FROM 
    TravelPlansInfo t
JOIN
    #temp_planned f ON f.travels != t.Route
)
INSERT into #temp_angle
SELECT ID, coord FROM rownum_matches rm WHERE rownum <= rowcnt
```

I tried to solve this issue by using a cursor but it was a mess. I would rather use a different alternative to cursors if possible. Input would be appreciated.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is much simpler.

```
insert into table
(f1, f2, etc)
select value1, value2, etc
where 
(select count(*)
from wherever) < 5
```

This assumes sql server where you don't need a where clause in a select query.